# How to get the class name and the value from an option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having an optgroup that's created by 2 queries from 2 tables. These tables are crossreferenced. One parent and one child. Now in my optgroup i have the value which are filled by id's and the class names indicate which table it is. Now I want to read these values in a js.

```
<option class="parent" value="1"></option>
<option class="child" value="4"></option>
```

Really hope someone can help me out.

Comment: Use the `className` property, just like any other element.

Comment: BTW, those are `option`, not `optgroup`.

Comment: Sorry that was my bad. I used to use an optgroup but I had to have the group selectable so it's changed back. Can i just do this to get the value: $("name_of_option").val(); and this to get the class name? $("filter_domain_incident").class.val();

Comment: The value works but how do i get the class value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the class of an element, use `.attr()`:

```
$('option[value=1]').attr('class');
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose this is your html:

```
<optgroup id='mygroup'>
    <option class="parent" value="1"></option>
    <option class="child" value="4"></option>
</optgroup>
```

Now to find class of first option

```
var className = $($('#mygroup').find('option')[0]).attr('class');
var value = $($('#mygroup').find('option')[0]).attr('value');
```

Comment: Nested calls to jQuery seem wrong, why not just `.find('option:eq(0)')`?